# When can "to" be followed by the present perfect, not the simple verb?

Tags: verbs

What is this sentence's grammar?
He needed to have delivered across the country.
Please explain it

Because as far as I know after "to" we should use simple verb but her after "to" was written ( have + PP )

Comment: Hello Reza.  Your Question title is "Hi, i have a question ,please"  This does not tell us about the question.  Your title should summarize the question.  I will edit.

Comment: You can also improve your question by telling us the source of the quote. Was it in a book or a movie?

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Please don't write comments asking other users to answer your question. Community members will answer your question if they feel confident and/or comfortable enough to write an answer. And if you find an answer helpful, instead of leaving a comment to thank them, please accept the answer and, when you have enough rep, upvote it.

Comment: can you please explain what the sentence is supposed to mean? It seems to be missing something.

Comment: The sentence should probably be "He needed to have **it** delivered across the country." The transitive verb "deliver" requires a direct object.

Answer (score 0):

The is a "[perfect infinitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked)".  It is used when the grammar requires an infinitive clause, but the verb in the infinitive is a completed action

> I want to play tennis

Main verb is present tense  "I want",  time of playing tennis is future.

> I like to eat bacon

Main verb is present tense "I like" time of eating is always

> I want to have played tennis

Main verb is present I want (so the desire is now)  But the playing of tennis has been completed. "I want to be in a state in which I have played tennis"

> I wanted to have played tennis

Main verb is past (the desire was in the past) and the playing of tennis was already completed "In the past I wanted to be in a state in which I had played tennis"

So you example

> He needed to have delivered across the country.

Means that "At that time there was a need.  That need was that the deliveries across the country were completed."

Comment: The perfect infinitive is a fiction invented by grammarians to confuse people. The infinitive is "to have". The main verb's participle is unchanged regardless of conjugation of the auxiliary verb.

Answer (score 0):

> as far as I know after "to" we should use simple verb

Yes, and that is exactly the case. The infinitive verb is the auxiliary verb "to have" and the main verb is the past participle as usual.  **When modifying a verb with an auxiliary it is always the auxiliary verb that conjugates not the main verb.**

*I have eaten*

*to have eaten*

Not complicated at all. I don't know why grammarians make such a fuss about it.